# PHP dynamically generate namespace based on folder structure

Tags: php, oop, dynamic, namespaces

I have a folder structure like so:

```
index.php
app/
    controllers/
                folder1/
                        class.php
```

There is no namespace definition in class.php. Would it be possible to put class.php in a namespace generated from folder structure relative to index? So it would be loaded like:

```
new \app\controllers\folder1\classInFile();
```

Or is there no way to dynamically create namespaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A file containing a namespace must declare the namespace at the top of the file before any other code.
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php

I.e., you cannot execute any code before the namespace declaration, and afterwards it's too late. Notwithstanding introspective runtime hacks: no, it's not possible. Even if it was, it would depend on runtime information, like what folder the code is executed/included from. The namespace could be `var\www\myproject\foo\bar\baz` or just `foo\bar\baz`. How are you going to determine that? That's getting messy.

Really, just make it *explicit*, even if that means typing a little more. The namespace is part of the class's *name*. You should not generate *names* dynamically at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be dynamically generating namespaces, the namespace cannot be set and read at compile time.

In any case, the namespace is provided/defined before any code is executed.

Answer (score 0):

The namespace needs to be defined inside of class.php if you can create the PHP source file dynamically, you can create the namespace dynamically.